# How do I get Eclipse-Che running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, eclipse-che

I'm trying to get Eclipse-Che to run on EC2, and I'm running into a few issues.
I can get the Eclipse-Che server to start if I only port-map 8080, but then I cannot connect to any workspaces, presumably because I'm missing ports 32768-32788.
If I map ports 32768-32788 in addition to 8080, then I cannot connect to the che server at all.

I've been reading the [Eclipse-Che docker usage documentation](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/usage-docker) and I can't figure out how to set the -it flags when I define my task on EC2.
I'm new to both Docker and EC2, so it isn't clear if those flags are important, nor if they'd be causing the behavior I'm seeing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are attempting to launch Che from the Docker container?  There is two ways to launch it - natively, or within a container.  I recommend the native approach.  You then just need to make sure that your EC2 node has 8080 and 32700+ ports opened to the external world. If you have more questions, you can get an issue posted to github.com/eclipse/che, and an engineer will respond.